# Maximum width for table column

Tags: html, css, html-table

I tried to set the maximum width for a column in a table (that is, I would like all the cells in that column to have the same maximum width), however my initial attempt failed:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr><td style="max-width:100px">a bunch of text here, it should get wrapped</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a bunch of text here, it should get wrapped</td></tr>
</table>
```

(also at http://jsfiddle.net/Le6H6/4/ )

I was expecting that setting the maximum width for one cell should automatically set it for all the cells in the same column. But somehow the cell in the second row overrules the maximum width I set, and both cells are wider than that width now.

I have 2 questions:

1. Why is this happening?
2. I know that setting the max width on every cell in that column (either individually or through an appropriate CSS rule) will achieve what I wanted. But is there also a way to set the maximum width for the column without setting it for every one of those cells?

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking, as evidenced by the numerous incorrect answers you've received. Please consider rephrasing your question in a more understandable way.

Comment: @RyanHenderson I don't really agree, but anyway I edited the question

Answer (score 2):

1) This is happening because this is how HTML tables work. The table re-sizes for the maximum cell width. It makes logical sense, if you think about it.

2) There are ways around this, but nothing that fits your constraints of adding a single style to a single cell.

Sorry if it's not the answer you're looking for. :/

Comment: 1) Do you have more details (e.g. excerpts from a standard)? It doesn't make much sense to me. 2) If not td, then I was hoping for something like the col element, but it doesn't seem to work either

Comment: 1) No, I'm sorry. I know from experience this is how it behaves, but I can't quote from the HTML spec. 2) What is forcing you into this constraint? Why can't you use any of the several workaround posted on this question?

Comment: 1) I know it does that when I have no width constraints (and I think it's normal), but I'd expect it to respect max-width of a cell. I'll see if more info comes up.. I guess I don't want to spend too much time digging into the spec. 2) Nothing is forcing me, I would just have preferred to have that option. I did use a css rule eventually (for all the cells in selected tables).

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that way because `max-width` can be applied on single cell. so u can use`<div>` to do it especially for that cell or make it for `<table>`

Try this :

```
<table border="1" style="max-width:100px;">
    <tr>
        <td>a bunch of text here, it should get wrapped</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>a bunch of text here, it should get wrapped</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

either use css

```
tr td { max-with :100px; }
```

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: Sometimes when 2 or 3 inline styling is done. then semicolon is necessary. m editing it..

Comment: Except here we have only 1 css attribute, and the semicolon does nothing

Comment: Ok, this version sets the max width for the whole table, which is definitely not what I wanted.